# Is there a way to reset jedis connection pool

Tags: connection-pooling, jmx, reset, jedis, spring-data-redis

This would be helpful to avoid restarting the JVM when we have a broken connection. For example, handling open Jedis issues like https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/916. I tried mBean route and the underlying GenericObjectPool doesn't expose any API to reset pool.  Hard or soft  pool reset will be super useful feature, something like what c3p0 connection pool offers.